# Use Openoffice "Export" option instead of "Save as" option in headless mode

Tags: html, openoffice.org, headless, jodconverter

Hi I am using JOD converter to convert documents to html.

I have tested converting doc file to html using openoffice(desktop mode) in two ways.

- **1st way: Using Save as option**

  The output file has lot of  tags which are deprecated from HTML4.
- **2nd way: Using "Export" option**

  The output file is clean with corresponding CSS.

FYI, I am using the below command to covert doc to html

> soffice --headless -convert-to html:"HTML (StarWriter)" inputfile.doc

In openoffice headless mode when I am trying to convert doc file it is using "Save as" instead of "Export" which is resulting lot of  tags. 
but, I want to use "Export" instead of "Save as" using command in headless mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found there is noway converting html to html5 in openoffice headless version and user [Tidy](http://w3c.github.io/tidy-html5/) to convert output html to html5.

with the command

```
tidy -c -m --indent true --doctype html5 inputfile.html
```